# Slider with a cookie

Tags: html, cookies, slider

Ok, let me get this straight. I have a bunch of images (around 20) in a slider. And there is a "Read More" button in the slides. Now, if a user clicks a slider,  it navigates to a certain page. And when the user navigates back to the page, the slider should start from the slide where he clicked. I hope you are getting my point. So, is there anyway I can achieve this?? Maybe a slider which can store cookies? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the index of page in local storage on every click.
2. When you load the page, check local storage. If the index is found, go to that slide.

You need to use some Javascript to achieve this.

Comment: I am not at all good at javascript.. Has some basic knowledge, but I don't think I can actually pull this one off alone.. Can you please shed some more light??.. Maybe a snippet of the code please

Comment: You need to provide code so that we can suggest fixes. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.